# How to force log4net to always use the same file

Tags: logging, configuration, log4net

I have a process that runs 2x a month and I want to log what's it doing and then send the log file in an email at the end. What I noticed when I ran it last night was that when it passed midnight it kept logging everything to `mylog.txt` but put the previous days logs in `mylog.txt.6-23-2011`. How do I tell it to not do that and always use the same file? Here's my configuration:

```
  <log4net>
    <appender name="ConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.SimpleLayout" />
    </appender>
    <appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="c:\logs\mylog.txt" />
      <appendToFile value="false" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <level value="ALL" />
      <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender" />
      <appender-ref ref="FileAppender" />
    </root>
  </log4net>
```

Comment: do not use a `RollingFileAppender` for this purpose then

Comment: ahhh...so if I change it to FileAppender then it will use the same file?

Comment: yes, as per @Kenny's answer below.

Comment: not sure why this was downvoted. I thought i WAS using the `FileAppender` but was accidentally using `RollingFileAppender`. Doh!

Comment: yep it happens. fair enough question i thought. i'll restore balance to the universe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the difference between FileAppender and RollingFileAppender [here](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html).  It sounds like you want FileAppender with appendToFile set to true.

```
<appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
    <file value="c:\logs\mylog.txt" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
</appender>
```